# How can I force `vagrant ssh` to do pseudo-tty allocation?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, tmux

The first thing I do after `vagrant ssh` is usually attaching to a `tmux` session.

I want to automate this, so I try: `vagrant ssh -c "tmux attach"`, but it fails and says "not a terminal".

After some googling I find [this article](http://jordanelver.co.uk/articles/2010/11/27/automatically-attaching-to-a-tmux-session-via-ssh/) and know that I should force a pseudo-tty allocation before executing a screen-based program, and it can be done with the `-t` option of `ssh`.

But I don't know how to use this option with `vagrant ssh`.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the problem or raise Vagrant issue?

Comment: So, it won't work - https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/2240

Answer (score 3):

According to [this documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh.html), you should try adding `--` to the command.
As I have not used [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/), I am unsure of the formatting, but assume it would be similar to:

`vagrant ssh -- -t`

Unless, you need to include the username and host, in which case add the username and host.

Comment: This doesn't work. I'm still looking for an example of this `--` option.

Comment: This seems to work `vagrant ssh -- -t 'tmux attach; /bin/bash'`