# start screen detached in a vagrant box with ssh, how?

Tags: ssh, vagrant, gnu-screen

Im stuck:

I have a Vagrant box with a server, when i logging with vagrant ssh, and launch my script to start the server in a detached screen session, is ok:

```
vagrant ssh

screen -d -m -S sesionServer bash run_server.sh
```

i can see my screen session active with screen -list and the server is running OK.

but i need launch all this in a single command, im trying to execute:

```
vagrant ssh -c 'screen -d -m -L -S test1 bash run_server.sh'
```

but I only have a "connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

How can i execute a screen command with vagrant ssh?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513513/how-can-i-force-vagrant-ssh-to-do-pseudo-tty-allocation) is the same question?

TL;DR `vagrant ssh` doesn't allocate pty to ssh session. Use `vagrant ssh -- -t` prefix before screen command.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set this in `Vagrantfile`:

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

```
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

    # Needed in order to run screen
    # https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html
    # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545745/start-screen-detached-in-a-vagrant-box-with-ssh-how
    config.ssh.pty = true
```