# Start a server running with screen in a vagrant box

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox, gnu-screen

I'm trying to run a server automatically when my vagrant box boots.

Similar to [start screen detached in a vagrant box with ssh, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27545745/start-screen-detached-in-a-vagrant-box-with-ssh-how), except I'm trying to do it with a provisioning script set to `run: "always"`.

I'm doing something like this: `nohup screen -S server -mL -d bash -c 'start-my-server.sh'`.

The server starts fine, and if I would have done this within the shell, I could switch to the server with `screen -r server`.

When I go in after with `vagrant ssh`, it doesn't find any screens...I'm assuming this is because its not the same shell session.

Is there anyway to get a hold of that screen session?

**Edit**
Forgot to mention that I had prefixed the screen command with `nohup`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run automatically program on startup under linux ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221757/run-automatically-program-on-startup-under-linux-ubuntu)

Comment: have you heard of `nohup`? I believe you should see the screen running from a second session unless the first was running under another user. What `ps` tells you?

Comment: I did try `nohup`, but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: @PauloScardine please explain what that question has to do with mine.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, but check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513513/how-can-i-force-vagrant-ssh-to-do-pseudo-tty-allocation

Comment: @PauloScardine, the question I linked to, links to that question as well, so obviously I saw it. I'm trying to run this in the context of a vagrant provision, not an ssh command on my running vagrant instance.

Comment: Ok...figured it out...vagrant runs the user as root, so it  _was_ a different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that vagrant provision was running as a privileged user, and therefore I couldn't see the screen logging in as the vagrant user.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out.